# Compressing figures for paper submission

Tags: journals, paper-submission, graphics

I recently submitted my first paper to a journal and had some trouble with the figures I uploaded. Specifically, the journal required vector graphics figures to be exported at 1200dpi, grayscale at 600dpi and coloured at 300dpi and I could choose between tiff and eps formats. The problem I faced was that there was an upload limit of 30MBs and I had to submit each figure separately. Keeping the dpi guidelines produced images that had a total size more than 200MBs and the only way I could upload them was by exporting them to 200dpi. Has anyone faced a similar issue and if so, how did you solve it?

Comment: What format are the images? I guess .eps
If you have access to a linux machine, you can use the command `ps2pdf` or `gs` to considerably reduce the size of your files.

Comment: How did the editor answer when you asked them this question? (You _did_ ask the editor, didn't you?)

Comment: I did answer but no reply yet.

Comment: Are you really sure that the journal requires you to convert vector graphics to pixel graphics? If yes, they are stupid. If no, just use vector graphics and your size problem should be gone.

Comment: In my experience, Matlab is very good at compressing figures in *.eps format(I have also used SciLab, Mathematica, R, but the best compressed images are produces with Matlab - 2D, 3D images, 3D histograms, density  contour plots, 3D object reconstruction, etc).

Comment: I didn't know that @Mikey Mike. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am assuming that the OP already is being careful to make the bitmapped images approximately the size that they will be printed (that is, the image should be 600dpi (or whatever) at the printed size, not the original size it was created just in case that was some default large format

Answer (score 1):

The upload limit is clearly a stricter requirement than the image resolution threshold since you can't submit a paper over that size. As you have done, I suspect most people would compress the images to meet the file limit.